# jQuery select the first hidden child in a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create some kind of an infinite scroll page that is static with the items on display:none. I've tried to use jQuery to show items 1 by 1 when scrolling but it doesn't work and I am not really sure why, please help if you can.

This is the script I've written so far:

```
functionyHandler(){  
    var wrap=document.getElementById('outer-1'); 
    var contentHeight=wrap.offsetHeight;  
    var yOffset=window.pageYOffset;  
    var y=yOffset + window.innerHeight;  
    if(y>contentHeight){ 
        $('#load-area').first(':hidden').removeClass('hide'); 
    }  
}
window.onscroll=yHandler;
```

My purpose is to remove class "hide" 1 by 1 while scrolling, meaning to select the first hidden child each time.

Comment: first() doesn't accept any argument. You cannot write `.first(':hidden')`

Comment: bro please provide html/css of it. html markups make more sense here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple, just do:

```
$('#load-area.hide:eq(0)').removeClass('hide');
```

Find the very first element with class 'hide' & remove class from that element.

--
HappyCoding

Answer (score 0):

Just combine the selector, [`first`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) doesn't take a selector as a parameter

**Although**, you're using multiple IDs? That won't work, so you'll need to use a class of `load-area` instead, then do:

```
$(".load-area:hidden:first");
```

As a last resort though, if you have no control over the markup and there's no classes you can use, then this will work for multiple IDs:

```
$("[id='load-area']:hidden:first");
```

Comment: the #load-area is the big div containing the small divs with .load-section classes

Comment: @VladEugenNitu So should it be `$("#load-area .load-section:hidden:first")`?

Comment: I'm a very beginner with a task that kind of overwhelms me to be very honest. In order to select the first hidden child of "#load-area" do I need to specify that the first child should be of class ".load-section"?

Comment: @VladEugenNitu No problems, you can specify that the child should be of class `.load-section` yeah. That could be a class, a tag name (like `div`), whichever you need.

Comment: if it helps any bit regarding the question, here is the link to the page so far:  <br/>   [link](http://www.2do.bestwebimage.ro/vlad-nitu/joellemagazine/categorie.html#)

Comment: ok I made it work using "$("#load-area :hidden:first").removeClass('hide');" but it shows only the first one. I want it to happen again when scrolling more with the next one that is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.load-area:hidden:first');
```

using class instead of ID. The Jquery code.